# playing a sound file in a pageControler with Xcode and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

I would like to play a sound file when a new page comes on the screen.

So far I did that to have the `pageControler` working with an array of images.

Can someone tell me where I have to put my code in order to play an array of sound? So that the `sound1` will be played when the `image1` comes on the screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
   @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

   var images: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
   var frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0, width:0, height:0)

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
      for index in 0..<images.count {
         frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
         frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

         let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
         imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
         self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)

      }

      scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
      scrollView.delegate = self
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      var pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
      pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a direct way to get called when the selected page changes. You could add code in your page view controller's `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)` method that figures out which page is active and plays the appropriate sound.

If you use a page control you could probably also subclass UIPageControl and use a didSet on the `currentPage` property to figure out which sound to play.

### Edit:

Just add a new file, make it a Cocoa touch class, and make it a subclass of `UIPageControl`. Name it `CustomPageControl`. Then your implementation can be as simple as this:

import UIKit

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            //Your code to play sounds based on selected index could go 
            //here, or broadcast a notification that your view controller 
            //would listen for
            print("New page index = \(currentPage)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then just select the page control on your UIPageViewController, select the "Identity Inspector", and change the class of the page control to your custom `CustomPageControl` class. Once you've done that, whenever your page index changes, the didSet method above will be called.

Comment: thx a lot! I will try but I don't know how to subclass UIPageControl. do you maybe have a link that can be useful for me? thank you very much for your time

Comment: No, I don't have a link. I pulled that idea out of my... hat. Yeah, my hat.

Comment: @davidandersson It just tried it and it works. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Ducan C: I tried but in the console I have that instead of the page numbers: 2018-11-20 15:54:20.707685-0500 audioBook[72322:3225706] CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal:566:  Threw error #201 (XML parsing failure)

Comment: Nowhere did we talk about XML. Looks like you have a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Ducan Cthe prob for the XML came from my pictures. I changed them and it is working. thx a lot!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it. (Click the check mark.) That is expected behavior on SO. Up-votes are uptional, but appreciated.

Comment: I did it. sorry I was new in the website